# On hover color not changing using LESS css

Tags: css, less, pug

I'm trying to change the color of text as well as background image, when hovered on the image. I'm using LESS and i am able to change the background image, but the color of the text is not getting changed. Please help. Here's my code snippet :-

Jade code ( .icon-photos will have an initial background image )

```
.icon-photos
div.icon-text
   | Photos
```

LESS code

```
.icons-holder .icon-photos:hover {
background: url('/assets/img/timeline/audio.png');
.icon-text {
    color: green;
 }
}
```

Comment: can you share youe HTML and say are you using SASS based CSS.

Comment: Are you sure `div.icon-text` is a child element of `.icon-photos`? That is what your Less code expects it to be.

Comment: @KawineshSK Please check this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVbVrr

Comment: @connexo You're right. I didn't 'div.icon-text' as the child element. Now i got it right. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Jade markup is wrong for the selector that you are using (or) your selector is wrong for the Jade markup that you have.

Your current markup as provided in the question is

```
.icon-photos
div.icon-text
   | Photos
```

and that when compiled would produce the below HTML output:

```
<div class="icon-photos"></div>
<div class="icon-text">Photos</div>
```

Note how the `.icon-text` is not the child of the `.icon-photos` and hence the CSS rules don't get applied. For the selector that you are using, the Jade code should be as below:

```
.icon-photos
  div.icon-text
   | Photos
```

Note the tab at the start of the second line which indicates it is a child. This would compile as below and hence would work with your selector.

```
<div class="icon-photos">
  <div class="icon-text">Photos</div>
</div>
```

---

If your markup is as per your expectation, then you should modify your CSS to use the adjacent sibling (`+`) or the general sibling (`~`) selector.